# Uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 and install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uninstall

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 looping log(more than 2 years) :)
and now I want to replace it by Ubuntu 20.04.2.0.
I have 4 partition
1 for windows (very important for me)
2 Ubuntu 14
3 and 4 are storage and normal usage

I start it from USB drive normally, and i faced this (erase ubuntu 14.04)
[all installing options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pXmY.jpg)

when I chose erase ubuntu it gives me this (option1)

[option1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/153vD.jpg)

and if I select the other choice (option3)

[option3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqZnx.jpg)

what it the safer option (need my windows and other data)

I don't need Ubuntu 14 data

Comment: You start by making a backup of everything you can not re-install and want or need to keep on any operating system and you also make sure you know how to restore the backup.  When you have more than 1 OS the "something else" installation method is the most informative and lets you adjust the most options. Just got to be careful.

Comment: in picture number 2 what SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) mean?

and partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) , partition #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)?

Answer (score 1):

I think option3 select the sda5 (your old ubuntu) check format & put a / in the mount options. When the next is clicked make sure only sda5 is being changed. Continue with install. You will wipe your old ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed as I was about to put when this popped up... You want you last one the picture showing the /dev/sda5 being used as the install partition. Clicking on the format box will erase all data on it for new install and make certain to select `/` as the mount point. When completed you should have 20.04.02 on the machine.

Comment: sda is the whole disk. sda5 is the partition that your old ubuntu is installed on. sda6 (partition 6) is another data partition.